# doubt about the meaning of the word "noch" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the phrase

> "Manchmal bin ich noch müde, wenn ich am Morgen ins Hotel komme."

whats the meaning of the word "noch" ?

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate more about your _"doubts"_.  The [google translation](https://translate.google.de/#view=home&op=translate&sl=de&tl=en&text=Manchmal%20bin%20ich%20noch%20m%C3%BCde%2C%20wenn%20ich%20am%20Morgen%20ins%20hotel%20komme.) almost yields exactly the same translation I've used in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is *still*

> > "Manchmal bin ich **noch** müde, wenn ich am Morgen ins hotel komme."

The correct translation to English is

> "Sometimes I am **still** tired, when I arrive at the hotel in the morning."

---

There are more uses of **noch** having completely different meanings:

1. Another

   > "Gib mir bitte **noch** ein Stück Kuchen"

   translates to

   > "Give me **another** piece of cake please."
2. Nor

   > "Das ist weder Fisch **noch** Fleisch."

   translates to

   > That's neither fish **nor** fowl [literally: "flesh"]."
3. Yet

   > "Bitte jetzt **noch** nicht."

   translates to

   > "Please not now **yet**."

Comment: Thanks! Can this word have another meaning ?

Comment: @GabrielSimões Yes there are other meanings like _"Gib mir bitte **noch** ein Stück Kuchen"_. That would translate to _"Give me **another** piece of cake please."_

Comment: Or: "Das ist weder Fisch **noch** Fleisch."/"That's neither fish **nor** fowl [literally: "flesh"]."

Comment: @Frank Danke für Deinen Beitrag. Ich glaube die Liste der Bedaeutungen von ***noch*** ist tatsächlich länger als gedachtt. Wenn Dir noch (sic!) mehr einfällt, fühle Dich bitte eingeladen meine Antwort zu ergänzen. Entsprechende Änderungsvorschläge werde ich aktzeptieren.